# Logic Issue - MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Following is my **MapKitDisplayViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
        region.center.latitude = 22.569722 ;
        region.center.longitude = 88.369722;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

        [mapView setDelegate:self];

        DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
        ann.title = [person name];
        ann.subtitle = [person address]; 
        ann.person = person;

        ann.coordinate = region.center; 
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
 (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
        if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
        {
                static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
                pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
                if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                                                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
                UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageWithString:@?????????????????];
                annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = iconView;

                pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
                pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
                pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
                } 

        return pinView;
}
```

You will see the line where it'll say `????????` I need to display an image there.

When the user clicks a pin point, then the popup will appear. Title, subtitle and the image is suppose to be displayed on the popup. I believe that the following line should display the image for that popup. But i am unable to pass the Person object's (or the pipoint which contains the person object) image URL to this method. Can you help me display the selected Image URL here.

Comment: Get rid of the?????s and show us the code that fails and tells us exactly how it fails.

Comment: It doesn't fail. I need to know how to pass the `person` object selected by the user to `viewForAnnotation` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did, in the `viewForAnnotation` method

```
DisplayMap *dm= (DisplayMap *)annotation;

NSString *url = [dm.person urlOfPerson];
```

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't fail. I need to know how to pass the person object 
>   selected by the user to viewForAnnotation method

Ahhh, I see know. I had a similar issue, and it can be a be tricky. I'm right in the middle of reworking my Annotation code, so you can see it since it doesn't work, but I you need to store something away that you can then later retrieve.

I made an object,  MKAnnotation.

```
@interface FotoMapLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
```

So when I make an annotation, I create a FotoMapLocation object.

```
    FotoMapLocation *annotation = [[FotoMapLocation alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                            subtitle:subtitle 
                                                                foto:aFoto 
                                                      thumbnailImage:aFoto.thumbnailImage
                               ];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Now, you can store *anything* here. So store your Person object in your subclass.

I know this is only halfway there, and very rambling. But I was right in the middle of ripping that code out, and then another fire came up, so it is currently in an in-between state. But I expect to return to it in a few days. I'll check back and if you don't have anything I'll update this answer.

Comment: So there isn't any other way to pass the `person` object the user selected to `viewForAnnotation` method ?

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean. You are already doing what I suggested, your "person" object is already in the annotation. Is the title or the subtitle unique? If so, keep an NSMutableDictionary around with using the title or subtitle as the key. Retrieve the person object that way? Wish my code was working right now, I'd just give it to you. But I'm a week away at least, preparing for VC funding this week.

Comment: I found a solution, and it works. I have included it as an answer. Have a look, hope it helps. And good luck for the VC funding :)

Comment: yup, you found something unique! That's great. Glad it worked out.